How stacked rods / multibank retinas cells are layered out?
I read that some animals have stacked rods in their eyes, usually fishes, a feature that as far as I know has the name of multibank retina.
I'm trying to understand how that is laid out in the retina alongside neural cells and retinal pigments, but I'm not finding any representation I can comprehend.
For example, this is an image of a human eye:

But I can't find anything close to representing a multibank retina that satiates my curiosity about this.
For example, I can't find how retinal pigments reach all rods & cones if the first one is layered, and if not, how that affects the cells (as far I know they help recycle used light-sensitive proteins). Or if horizontal cells extend to reach the deeper rods or the rods extend themselves towards the horizontal cells), or the same with the retinal pigments. If ganglions and bipolar cells are layered together or the entire retina is doubled, having two sections of ganglion->bipolar->rod/cone->ganglion->bipolar->rod. Nor if cones are only found in the first layer, the last one, or all layers. Or if müller cells extend towards all layers since as far I know they help propagate light to cones. There are so many questions that I could answer with a single picture.
Since I could not find many papers which aren't behind a paywall or too complex for me to understand, I tried luck asking in a chat about biology, and I only got that they have "more photoreceptors layers that project further back up towards the ganglia layers", which I didn't understand much. Does that mean something like this?:

It sounds wrong, like some photoreceptors never get into contact with retinal pigment cells (which recycles photoreceptor disks), and now the wiring is much dense, blocking photons from reaching cones (which the eye doesn't have more to compensate). Is this correct?
Also, if photoreceptors are stacked, then the ones which are further from the choriocapillaris (the largest network of blood capillaries in the eye, which is located after the retinal pigmented cells) would receive less oxygen and I have understood that these cells consume an enormous amount of oxygen. Does the cell's layout take this into account in some way?
What about tapetum lucidum? Is it located after the last layer of rods or does each one have its own? The first one would increase the distance between the receptors and the reflective structure, blurring the image as photons bounce in different directions, but the second one would make the following layers quite useless as the layer mirrors light. Or do multibank eyes have no tapendum lucidum?
Seeing a representation of the layout would allow me to know what "tradeoff" has these types of eyes.

Why do photoreceptors need to contact retinal pigment cells? Does an animal that needs a bunch of extra rods to detect light have any use for cones anyways? What would make the photoreceptors further from blood vessels?

@BryanKrause Honestly my knowledge is limited, but AFAIK, (1) cones/rods remove old opsins and they are absorbed by pigment cells and recycled. (2) some teleost fishes have multibanks and they live in coral reefs, which have light, so I suppose they have color vision. (3) if roods are stacked, some layers will be closer to the outer blood vessels which surround the retina from the back, while others don't, isn't it?

Tissues get fed by capillaries, not larger vessels. Recycling opsins is not something I was familiar with, thank you. My understanding is that the multibanks are a specialization for extreme low light conditions. Of course, evolution isn't perfect and it's certainly possible that a fish that evolved specializations for low light moves into a different niche where those specializations don't make as much sense.

@BryanKrause I see, I may be wrong about how photoreceptors get oxygen. I know that evolution isn't perfect, so an adaptive trait may become maladaptive in a different environment, which in my opinion it only makes me more eager to know how evolution attempts to fix such details, if it actually tries and how that is reflected in the current layout of such organism. However, I still believe the rest of the question to be valid enough to ask if you don't mind.

@BryanKrause This is what I mean with blood vessels, or capillaries, they are next to pigmented cells, difficulting stacked rods to reach them. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/353406543/figure/fig3/AS:11431281212543395@1702652163031/Transport-mechanisms-for-delivering-nanoparticles-NPs-into-the-blood-retinal-barrier.tif

Capillaries run throughout the retina. They are not only next to pigmented cells. Yes, I think it's a valid question. Not sure this paper will answer all your questions but seems relevant: https://pmc.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/articles/PMC10688437/

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

As far as I can tell, multibank retinas are associated with deep-sea or nocturnal fish. Here is a histology image from Multiple rod layers increase the speed and sensitivity of vision in nocturnal reef fishes (this is a BioRxiv paper, so you should be able to access it.):


Fig. 1. Retinal structure and cell densities.
A. Representative radial sections from the retina of i) O. compressus, ii) N. sammara and iii) M. violacea. Rod banks are numbered as Bn. Representative rod and cone outer segments are indicated by black and white arrows, respectively. B. Densities of different types of retinal cells in O. compressus (n=1), N. sammara (n=1) and M. violacea (n=1). PRL, photoreceptor layer; ONL, outer nuclear layer; INL, inner nuclear layer; GCL, ganglion cell layer; GC, ganglion cells. Scale bars: 25 μm (Ai), 50 μm (Aii and Aiii).

O.compressus, pictured on the left, has a single rod bank, while the other two fish have multiple. Note that the scale bar on the left represents 25 microns while the center and right are 50, so while the single rod bank appears to be the same depth as the multiple banks, it is actually about half. This is outside the scope of the paper, but if I am interpreting their figure correctly, one difference with your diagram is that the cell bodies of the rods aren't stacked in the multibank array with their photoreceptive outer segments, but are all clustered together in the Outer Nuclear Layer.
Regarding the regeneration of opsin, I found that Müller cells can provide chromophores to the cones, through a separate visual cycle with a different opsin chromophore precursor. The energy for this regeneration is provided by light captured by "repurposed" opsins in the Müller cells. Source is RDH12 allows cone photoreceptors to regenerate opsin visual pigments from a chromophore precursor to escape competition with rods . So the cones being separated from the RPE by more banks of rods isn't an issue.
